# how to run function when changing the value of a field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning,
as the title suggests, how to run function (JavaScript) when changing the value of a field (no from empty in compiled)?

Comment: Can you show your code? Do you mean the onchange event?

Comment: Hi Filippo!  You should expand this question and include more details to get better answers.  (and don't forget to check if someone's asked the same question before you...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check on each key press then

**With javascript**

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" onkeyup="TextBoxChanged()" />

function TextBoxChanged(){
   alert("changed");
}
```

**With jquery**

This requires you to import [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) file to be imported in the web page.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/9yyPP/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#textbox').keyup(function() {
      alert("changed");
  });​
});
```

Bind change event with textbox, this will cause event when textbox loses focus.

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#textbox').change(function(){
      alert("changed");
   });
});
```

Comment: `keyup` is not very generic. The `input` event is also triggered on paste/drop etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('#select_id').change(function(){
       //Do your code here
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add better that

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     $('select_id').live('change',function(){
          //Do your code
 });
})
```

it will be better and suggestable also

Answer (score 0):

You first define an id or class for the input field like that

```
<input type="text" id="myId" />
```

then you bind a function to his change event like this

```
function myFunction(){
  // Your function here !
}
$('#myId').change(function(){
   // Your function call here
   myFunction();
});
```